# Powershell performing -replace on .csv object

Tags: powershell, replace, export-csv

Fairly simple request but struggling.
I have a .csv file with 30 columns. One column 'sku' has product codes in it which I need to modify.
I then need to write all the data including the modified column, back to the original file.

So far I have selected and expanded the 'sku' object and used some regex to do the modifications, this works as expected.

However if I export the file using Export-Csv I only get the text property value .length.
I suspect because -replace is implicitly converting the object to a string?

Also I'm not selecting any of the other columns as I can't figure out how to select all the other properties and do the -replace together.

Please help me out.

```
$CSVFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Exports\Test\AMAZON -File -Filter '*.csv' | Where Extension -eq '.csv'
foreach ($csv in $CSVFiles) {
$csvOutput = Import-Csv $csv.FullName
$sku = $csvOutput | Select-Object -ExpandProperty sku | 
Foreach-Object {$_ -replace '^.*?(?=T)',''} | 
Export-Csv $csv.FullName -NoType
}
```

Comment: as for why you are failing with your current method - you are throwing out everything other than SKU value ... what would you _expect_ to see after that? [*grin*] ///// iterate thru the collection in `$CsvOutput`, modify the value in the target property, and _then_ export the full object collection.

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes I can see why you would grin. And I understand what you mean. I just don't know how to do it :)

Comment: i see that `Olaf` showed a solution that seems to cover your needs. glad to know that you got it working ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `Select-Object -ExpandProperty` you turn rich and powerfull objects with properties into stupid text. ;-)

This should be closer to what you need:

```
$CSVFiles = 
Get-ChildItem -Path D:\Exports\Test\AMAZON -File -Filter '*.csv'
foreach ($csv in $CSVFiles) {
    $csvOutput = Import-Csv $csv.FullName
    $csvOutput | 
    Foreach-Object { 
        $_.sku = $_.sku -replace '^.*?(?=T)'
        $_ 
    } | 
    Export-Csv -Path $csv.FullName -NoTypeInformation -Force
}
```

Comment: Hi Olaf, Your suggestion gives me the .length of the $_.sku property Lee_Dailey is correct in that I need to iterate through $CsvOuput. But I don't know how

Comment: @ColinA You're right. Changed the code accordingly.

Comment: Thank You. This works perfectly. Can you explain, how does the -replace know how to replace the character before T with nothing as the following ,'' has been removed?

Comment: @ColinA You provided the regex pattern! ;-)  ... if you just want to remove something from a string you can omit the "*replace with*" part of the command.

Comment: Apologies, I'm confused. Normal syntax I believe would be -replace '^.*?(?=T)' , '' My understanding is that I'm giving -replace the search pattern and THEN telling it with , '' to replace whatever it finds with nothing. However in your code you have removed , '' So how does it know what to replace the matching pattern with? You are saying that -replace '^.*?(?=T)' automatically removes the match and that only if I wanted to replace the match with something else would I use: -replace '^.*?(?=T)' ,'something else'?

Comment: @ColinA  Yes. ;-)  Both ways work the same. Either `-replace '^.*?(?=T)' , ''` or `-replace '^.*?(?=T)'`. But for me the second version looks more clear.